# how to redirect from a view in keystone.js

Tags: async.js, keystonejs

What is the right way to redirect from within a keystone.js view?

I have this use case:

```
//req, res are the express request and response objects defined earlier
view.on('init', function(next){
 if (req.params['should-be-else-where']='true'{
    // do some logging stuff 
    // redirect to somewhere else
  }
});
```

as I understand the next param in the `view.on()` function is a callback for the async.js framework, and does not relate to the (req,res,next) middleware.

Should I call `res.redirect('/somewhere-else)` and then call `next()`, then call `next()` with a non-null error parameter, or should redirection be performed somewhere completely different?

Additional info: I'd like to stop processing because there is no reason to do the performance heavy database processing that following later in the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a View but only redirect if the condition was met, you could do it like this:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.params['should-be-else-where']) {
        // do some logging stuff 
        res.redirect('/somewhere-else');
    } else {
        var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
        // do something else then render the view
    }

}
```

Comment: This topic is also nicely discussed here https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/303 with some other tips on Redirections in KeystoneJS.